# Dynamically create metadata terms

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, filter

Use case:

1. SP List synced to Access database.
2. Database gets data from an external app and updates list dynamically.
3. The value in one field gets added to metadata term set.
4. Users can search/filter the list by values in that field using metadata filter box.

1 and 2 work fine, **I'd like to add 3 and 4**.